# configure Unity to resolve a constructor parameter and interface

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have a FaxService class that takes two constructor parameters.

```
public FaxService(string phone, IFaxProvider faxProvider)
```

How is Unity configured to send a string for the first parameter and an IFaxProvider instance for the second?  I realize I can inject another service that provides the string, but I am looking for a solution where I don't have to change the FaxService constructor parameters.

This is what I have so far...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        var phone = "214-123-4567";
        container.RegisterType<IFaxProvider, EFaxProvider>();
        container.RegisterType<IFaxService, FaxService>(phone);

        var fax = container.Resolve<IFaxService>();
    }
}

public interface IFaxService { }

public interface IFaxProvider { }

public class FaxService : IFaxService
{
    public FaxService(string phone, IFaxProvider faxProvider) { }
}

public class EFaxProvider : IFaxProvider { }
```

but it throws...

> Unity.Exceptions.ResolutionFailedException   HResult=0x80131500
>   Message=Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   'ConsoleApp3.IFaxService', name = '(none)'. Exception occurred while:
>   while resolving.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
var phone = "214-123-4567";
container.RegisterType<IFaxProvider, EFaxProvider>();
container.RegisterType<IFaxService, FaxService>(new InjectionConstructor(phone, typeof(IFaxProvider)));

var fax = container.Resolve<IFaxService>();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this results in System.InvalidOperationException
  Message=The type ConsoleApp3.FaxService does not have a constructor that takes the parameters (String).  Also, I tried an array of InjectionConstructors that specify the string and IFaxProvider.

Comment: You can eliminate the second registration and add the constructor to the first: `container.RegisterType<IFaxService, FaxService>(new InjectionConstructor(phone, typeof(IFaxProvider)));`.

Comment: @NightOwl888 thanks for the suggestion, updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a solution where I don't have to change the FaxService constructor parameters.

There is nothing built into Unity to do this without specifying at least the types of all constructor parameters.

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
var phone = "214-123-4567";
container.RegisterType<IFaxService, FaxService>(new InjectionConstructor(phone, typeof(IFaxProvider)));
container.RegisterType<IFaxProvider, EFaxProvider>();

var fax = container.Resolve<IFaxService>();
```

The list of parameters would need to change every time the constructor changes.

### Workaround

If you don't want to change your DI registration if the constructor changes for `FaxService`, build an abstract factory to separate the string/primitive parameters from the services. Pass services through the constructor parameters of the factory. Pass string and primitive parameter types through the `Build` method parameters.

```
public class FaxServiceFactory
{
    private readonly IFaxProvider faxProvider;
    public FaxServiceFactory(IFaxProvider faxProvider)
    {
        this.faxProvider = faxProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(faxProvider));
    }

    public IFaxService Create(string phone)
    {
        return new FaxService(phone, this.faxProvider);
    }
}
```

And then register like:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

var phone = "214-123-4567";
container.RegisterType<FaxServiceFactory>();
container.RegisterType<IFaxProvider, EFaxProvider>();
container.RegisterInstance<IFaxService>(container.Resolve<FaxServiceFactory>().Create(phone));

var fax = container.Resolve<IFaxService>();
```

Another possibility is to use a DI container that allows you to specify partial lists of constructor parameters (Autofac, Ninject, StructureMap, and Castle Windsor all do this out of the box).